# How to link crypto shared library in Android JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk, cryptography, java-native-interface, shared

I am writing a wrapper to use some functions of crypto.
I build crypto lib from [openssl-android](https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android) with Android-NDK. Now i have the libcrypto.so that i need, but i don´t know how to link it with my wrapper.

My project tree is like this

```
(proj root)
|
|->(src)
|->(src)-> com.package
|->(src)-> com.package->NativeCipher.java
|
|->(jni)
|->(jni)->Android.mk
|->(jni)->NativeCipher.c
```

NativeCipher.java

```
public class NativeCipher {
    static {
         System.loadLibrary("crypto");
         System.loadLibrary("NativeCipher");
     }

     public static native byte[] AESEncrypt(byte[] in, byte[] key);
}
```

NativeCipher.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <aes.h>

jbyteArray Java_com_package_NativeCipher_AESEncrypt(JNIEnv* env, jobject this, jbyteArray in, jbyteArray key)
{
    // All my code here
}
```

I need to use the functions of #include that crypto provides.
However, i don't know what to do with the .so files that NDK generates and how to make the Android.mk file to build.

Thanks in advance, i tried to be as specific as posible.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you able to build the .so files? Do you get an error when trying to use them?

Comment: I dont know where i have to put the libcrypto.so and how to write the Android.mk of my NativeCipher files (java and .c) to build them. Sorry, i am new at this kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

Native libraries go to the `libs/armeabi` or `libs/armeabi-v7a` of your Android project. You might want to rename the OpenSSL library though, because the system already has a `libcrypto.so`. As for your own JNI wrapper, just take the shared library sample from the NDK and modify to use your own files.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, where i can find that NDK sample? I just have to copy and paste the libcrypto.so to libs/armeabi (builded with another name) and i can include<aes.h> ?

Comment: The NDK includes a number of sample projects, familiarize yourself with those. At least one shows you how to incorporate a shared library, use it as starting point for your own project.